# Data transformation in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, conversion, pivot-table

looking for help on converting data from one format to another -

If you want to see data in sheet is here - 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yO90XjjN2c80ReYMIXTdS7e8SLb2NNMRNqiXbqR8J2k/edit?pli=1#gid=555602833

I tried using PIVOT table, but it did not work, also another issue with that is, pivot table did not refresh as data is changed.

View sample data and output - Image - http://postimg.org/image/5gdyhs5gh/
[image]

Description -
1. Transpose primary data set and organize data so that options are shown as columns.
2. If there are multiple rows for same product and same option, need to sum it up and add as one row.
3. If products are not available for certain option then we need to update that cell as 'NA'
4. 'Primary set of data' may contain multiple rows, but it will have only 3 options at given point of time.
5. Above 3 scenarios are just for explanation of this problem, I want to develop one table which is dynamic
and changes are reflected as I make updates to data

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need to use VBA for this.
[image] 
Two types of formula used:

- `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$B$2:$B$9),0,0),0)),"")` - to display product names, fill it from F1 to down as much cells as much products you expect
- `=IF($F2="","", IFERROR(1/(1/SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9,$A$2:$A$9,G$1,$B$2:$B$9,$F2))&" ("&SUMIFS($D$2:$D$9,$A$2:$A$9,G$1,$B$2:$B$9,$F2)&")","NA"))` to calculate sums of prices and quantities, put in columns for Options 1 - 3 and fill down with column of product names.

As all are standard formula it'll update automatically when you change your data.